# how to create next/previous buttons to query MySQL rows by date?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I assume, I need Ajax and jQuery to show new data based on date after clicking a button.

What I want to do is something like this:

> **<< January 15**................today: January 16..............**January 17 >>**
>
> Data4
>
> Data5
>
> Data6

When I click "January 17" *data 4-6* should change to *data 7-9* because *data 7-9* is added to the MySQL database on January 17.

Of course I have a code to query the database and show today's data, but I am going crazy about not being able to reload the page with new data.

I tried to search the whole internet, but nothing I can find fits my needs.

Comment: The question is too abstract. This could be achieved in a number of ways. E.g. you could load all data at once and show/hide data on the front end side. Or you could send separate AJAX/HTTP requests for each day to your back end.

Comment: If you search the whole internet and can't find anything, then you're searching for the wrong thing.  In your case, it isn't even clear what the problem is... and that's the core of the issue here.  Why do you assume you need AJAX?  Why do you assume you need jQuery?  And what does that have to do with a `WHERE` clause in your query?

Comment: You searched the whole Internet? Did you consider programming it yourself?

Comment: @barmar: I am a beginner and I searched the internet for examples, because obviously I can't code it myself.

Comment: @Jev Zelenkov: I have a few hundred thousand rows. I can't load everything and just hide what I don't need. About Ajax: yes, but how? I have no clue, that's why I am asking.

Comment: Your query should have `WHERE DATE(datetimecolum) = '2015-01-17'` when you select `January 17`. When you go to the next day, the date in the query changes to `2015-01-18`, and so on.

Comment: @Brad:  I don't understand, what is not clear about what I want. There is a list of names for example, like registered users. I want to show the list of names based on date they registered.

Comment: @Hunnenkoenig Answer the three questions I asked, and it will be much clearer.

Comment: @Barmar: I know what I have to do. I don't know HOW. As I said, I query and show today's data. That's not the problem how I query for date. The problem is: how do I change the query dynamically and reload the page?

Comment: @Brad: Why do you assume you need AJAX? Because I need to reload the new data in the same page. Why do you assume you need jQuery? I think it is working with AJAX... I am not sure what it is. And what does that have to do with a WHERE clause in your query? To change the date dynamically.

Comment: @Hunnenkoenig So, your question actually has nothing to do about querying by date?  It's about how to use AJAX with jQuery?  Your question says otherwise right now... it's like you've combined two issues into one and they're really completely unrelated.  Please pick one question, and open up a new question for the other.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting us to tell you. If pointing you in the general direction isn't enough, it seems like we'd have to write it for you.

Comment: @Brad: I have no clue what AJAX and jQuery really is. I just assume by what I have seen on the net, that I need those if I want to reload a page by a button click with a new query. If I knew what they do and how they are different things, then I would ask the question more specific. I just know that I have MySQL database, my page is in PHP and I need to query and reload the page with new data in the same page. That's all I am asking. How do I do that?

Comment: @Barmar: Telling "You need Ajax" is not "pointing into the right direction". I searched the net the whole day looking for solutions and examples. That's why I asked about Ajax.

Comment: @Hunnenkoenig AJAX is a way to make an HTTP request for data without reloading a page.  If you want to get fresh data on your page without reloading, then you are right, that's what you need.  jQuery is a JavaScript library with a lot of convenient functions and browser polyfills for doing all sorts of things, including AJAX.  Now that you know your question is two questions, try Googling again.  You'll find thousands (millions?) of tutorials on jQuery and AJAX.

Comment: @Brad: Let's turn it around: What do I need if I want a button, that shows me the new data after the user clicked it? I am not a programmer. I understand basic logic and I can hack example codes to a limited extent. If I were a programmer, I wouldn't come here and ask so stupid.

Comment: @Hunnenkoenig AJAX, and update the text with the result.  Seriously, if you Google "AJAX jQuery tutorial", there are so many resources for you.  For example:  http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/  It is impossible to help you when we don't have any idea where you are stuck, specifically.  You're going to have to learn some more before your project is going to work.  Start with fully understanding what it is you're trying to do, and how you would implement.

Comment: @Barmar: I tried many things based on examples which did completely different things, than expected. I can't show anything, because nothing worked, not even a little bit. But you know what? Forget it. Thanks anyway! I will ask somebody on monday who actually can show me this probably in 3 minutes, because I assume, it doesn't take longer, if you know what you do.

Comment: @Brad: If you knew, what I already tried to google in all combinations... I need examples. I can't read books about ajax going nowhere. Unfortunately all specific tutorials about date and buttons are completely different things, not even remotely similar to what I want to do. They show paginations and calendars, which are both nice, but not what I need. Anyway... thanks.

Comment: @Bramar: Oh and btw if you would have read my post, then you would have seen, that "I have the code for today's data". I didn't post the code, because a simple mysql query SELECT * FROM things WHERE datum = '".$today."' " is even for me trivial. I just needed a helping hand for how to change the date and tie it to a button. Thanks for the -1!

Comment: @Hunnenkoenig The tutorial I linked to is filled with examples.  And, what I'm trying to tell you is that the date pickers and what not have absolutely nothing to do with what you need.  You need to separate the two pieces two your problem.  If you cannot do that, you really need to consider hiring someone who can.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a lot of sides to it. This answer's solely purpose to demonstrate how front end, back end and persistence layer communication works.

#### DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION! THIS CODE IS SHITTY AND FOR DEMO PURPOSES ONLY!

> Modern web applications are not implemented like this. Front end frameworks/libraries are commonly used to keep complexity manageable.

---

First of all your back end should provide an API to the front end.

Lets assume your back end accepts the following HTTP GET request:

```
www.example.com/users/list_by_date/20150131
```

The last parameter is a date in `YYYYMMDD` format. Upon receiving this request, your back end sends a pre-rendered HTML snippet containing a list of users from that date. (Nowadays front end side rendering is quite popular and you should look into that topic as well. In this case your back end sends a list of users in JSON format which is then rendered on the front end side using templates. Adding code for this would make example even more complex).

In order to get this list of users, you initiate an AJAX request from the front end when a user clicks on a `next-day` button (which in your example contains "January 17"). Furthermore, you need to replace a list of currently shown users from January 16th with the new ones. Lets assume that list has a class attribute `.users` in HTML code. Here is a front end code using jQuery:

```
$(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.next-day', function() {
    $.getJSON("/users/list_by_date/20150131", renderResults);
  });

  function renderResults = function(data) {
    $('.users').html(data); // replaces old contents with the new ones received from server
  };
});
```

You should also update prev/next link titles to the next dates, January 16th and January 18th respectively.

On the back end side, you execute a SQL statement to fetch a list of users. It could look something like this:

```
SELECT * from Users where DATE(datetimecolum) = '2015-01-17'
```

The exact way to put an attribute into a SQL query varies among programming languages/frameworks.

This should help you start working on your own solution. You probably should at least consider a front end framework/library to help you manage the complexity. You might want to spend a few days or even weeks getting familiar with front end technologies before attempting to implement a good solution on your own. It might be more cost efficient to hire a front end developer.

Answer (score 0):

I did it on my own and the code actually were 5 lines.

I needed 2 days. Somebody who knows it, could have written it up in 2 minutes. So thanks for all the fish!

Here is the code, if somebody ever needs something like this:

The code for determining the very last date available (which I had already):

```
$query = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT MAX(datum) as max_datum, MIN(datum) as min_datum FROM apps WHERE price = 0 ") or die(mysqli_error());
$maxdate = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$maxdate = $maxdate['max_datum'];
$mindate = $mindate['min_datum'];
```

**The actual code I was looking for** to display two links for next and previous days (without design):

```
$date = isset($_GET['date']) ? $_GET['date'] : $maxdate;
$prev_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' -1 day'));
$next_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' +1 day'));

if ($date < $maxdate) {
echo "<a href=?date=$next_date>forward a day</a>";
}
if ($date > $mindate) {
echo "<a href=?date=$prev_date>back a day</a>";

}
```

The code executing the data which I had already:

```
$result = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT * FROM apps WHERE datum =  '".$date."' AND price = 0 ") or die(mysqli_error());
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "<div id='icon-wrapper'>";


$cc = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

...

    $cc++;
    if ($cc < $count) {
    echo "\n";
    }
}

echo "</div>";
mysqli_close($bd);

?>
```